# Notification not starting a activity with action in android

Tags: android, notifications

I 've put a button in the program .
When clicked , a notification is made ​​.
The following code runs properly , and a notification is made.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button create=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_creat);

    create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayNotification(getAppleationContext());
        }
    });

}
 public void displayNotification(Context context) 
{

  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new      NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
  .setContentTitle("berhooz")
  .setContentText("ahmadi hastam")
  .setTicker("hello")
  .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SecoundActivity.class);
         notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);//single top to avoid                //creating many activity stacks queue
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

But I'd rather use this piece of code

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SecoundActivity.class);
```

I use the following code:
(Call a activity using action)

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("aa.bb.cc.dd");
```

But when I click on the Notification nothing happens !

in AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity android:name="SecoundActivity"></activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="aa.bb.cc.dd"></action>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start Activity using custom Action you also need to specify `category` as `DEFAULT` in  `intent-filter` :

```
 <activity android:name="SecoundActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="aa.bb.cc.dd" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```